# Magento 2 : Is there any way to calculate life time sales, without create invoices for the order from the Magento side?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, payment-gateway, magento2, klarna

I have integrated Klarna checkout with Magento web shop. When the payment is success for an order, order status is changing to complete (As I configured) in Magento side. But it is not updating the life time sales without create invoices for the orders.  But I do not need to make any invoices. Is there any way to by pass this invoice creation and update the life time sales with completed or processing orders?